PowerShell Get-ChildItem returns multiple, identical values - how do I compare them and select the right one?
I am trying to trap the DisplayVersion after an install completes to verify that the target version of the application is installed rather than just any version is installed. I'm really close to ironing this out except that because the current program has multiple components, the validation logic fails.
To clarify: I am checking both of these locations because some programs only show up in one but not the other. This program shows up in the WOW6432Node twice, and so when I call $InstallVersion it returns the DisplayVersion for both components it detects, but since they are the same, it just has the same value twice.
$InstallVersion = (Get-ChildItem HKLM:\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall),(Get-ChildItem HKLM:\SOFTWARE\WOW6432Node\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall)| foreach {
    [String](Get-ItemProperty $_.Name.Replace("HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE","HKLM:") -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue | Where {$_.DisplayName -like '*AnyConnect Secure Mobility Client*'}).DisplayVersion 
}

For additional information, when I call $InstallVersion after this, I get 4.10.08025 4.10.08025
I need to find a way to just get one or the other.
I tried finding a way to use Select-Object to do this, but I was not able to iron out the syntax.
Now, ideally, I'd love to find a way to recursively compare every value this query returns, one at a time (whether it is 2 identical values, or 27 unique values) and then create some kind of If statement where if all 2-27 values are exactly the same, then it consolidates them, validates, and moves on.
So if it comes back with 4.10.08025 4.10.08025 4.10.08025 4.10.08025 4.10.08025 4.10.08025 it would change the variable to just one 4.10.08025 instead of more than one.
However, if there are 2 or more unique values returned, like 4.10.08025 4.10.07073 4.10.06078
I can write to the log indicating something like "I found the one you are looking for, but I also found a few others, so you might be fine, but you might not."
There's also the chance I may just be trying to use a hammer instead of a screwdriver and the experts reading over them get a really red forehead after reading it.

You're correct with trying to use Select-Object to get unique values in your result, syntax below. As for checking if the version you want is within the result you can use a containment operator (-in or -contains).
$paths = @(
    'HKLM:\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall'
    'HKLM:\SOFTWARE\WOW6432Node\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall'
)

[array] $versions = Get-ChildItem $paths |
    Where-Object { $_.GetValue('DisplayName') -like '*AnyConnect Secure Mobility Client*' } |
    ForEach-Object { $_.GetValue('DisplayVersion') } |
    Select-Object -Unique

# or whatever version
if ($versions -contains '4.10.08025') {
    if ($versions.Count -gt 1) {
        # here is for, you're good, the version is installed
        # but you have more than 1 installed
    }
    else {
        # here is for you're good, you have the version installed
        # and no other
    }
}
else {
    # here the version you want is not installed
}


no need to cast it to a array, the pipeline already returns an object array
